# Promisify aws streams

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, promise, aws-sdk

I want to download multiple files from S3 and once they all finish to download do something else.
I am using the following code to download the files:

```
function downloadFiles(folder, files) {

    var params = {
        Bucket: bucket
    }

    files.forEach(function (file) {
        params.Key = folder + '/' + file;
        var fileStream =  fs.createWriteStream(config.s3_downloaded_files_folder + file);
        S3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(fileStream);
    })
}
```

How do I promisify this code so I can execute some code once all files finished to download?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For streams, you can use the `finish` event to determine that the stream has finished. At this point, you can resolve the promise.  You can create an array of promises for this:

```
Promise.all(files.map(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileParams = Object.assign({Key: folder + "/" + file}, params);
    let fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(config.folder + file);
    S3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(fileStream);
    file.on("finish", () => resolve());
    file.on("error", err => reject(err));
})));
```

Now you can chain `.then` to `Promise.all` which is resolved once all of the promises you have created are resolved.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect.